# Extjs 3.4 Window not draggable with DOCTYPE

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using estjs 3.4.
On my html pages I am not using a DOCTYPE, and I have a css menu on these pages.
Without the DOCTYPE the menu renders correctly in Firefox, Chrome and Opera, also my extjs windows are draggable. When I use IE9 the css menu does not render correctly so I need to put a DOCTYPE, the problem then is that with the DOCTYPE the extjs  windows are no longer draggable in IE9 and chrome. Is there a way to over come this so that both the css menu displays correctly and the windows are draggable in all browsers.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: Did you found a solution/workaround in the end? I am facing the same issue...